# Is it allowed to use subclass constructor in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

As in the title. In example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,surname):
        self.surname=surname

obj=B('somename','somesurname')
```

If it's allowed, in which order shall I pass parameters in object instantiation?

Comment: If you want your `B` initialiser to take both names as parameters, you need to write an `__init__` that takes both names as parameters. You can call `A`'s `__init__` from inside `B`'s `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly call the constructor of the super-class from your derived one:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.surname=surname

obj=B('somename','somesurname')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) builtin function:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.surname=surname

obj=B('somename','somesurname')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new constructor should call the parent constructor if the old constructor must be executed. You can call the parents constructor using [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.surname = surname

obj = B('somename', 'somesurname')
```

In python 2, you must specify the current class and self as arguments to `super()`: `super(B, self)`, in python 3 it can be called without arguments like as shown above.